# how to find the csv file has only header using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I need to find out if the given csv doesn't have any values other than header using batch script.

I'm trying with below line but my batch script is just flashing. Guide me to get the expected result.

```
(for /f "skip=1" %%a in ('type response.csv') do if "%%a"=="" (
set isDataPresent= No
echo %isDataPresent%
)
if %isDataPresent% EQU No goto noRecords
)
:noRecords
echo file is blank
[do something]
```

Comment: There is no chance for `"%%a"` to be equal to `""`, because `for` skips empty lines (if you have just the header, with `skip=1`, there is no data to be processed, so the `if "%%a"...` isn't even executed. But you can use this - see my answer.

Comment: This is more compact though more complex way: `(for /F "usebackq skip=1" %%a in ("response.csv") do rem/) && (echo records found) || (echo file is blank)`

Answer (score 1):

You have a [delayed expansion problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028).
May I suggest another (simpler) approach?

```
for /f "skip=1" %%a in (response.csv) do goto :data
echo no data.
goto :eof
:data 
echo data available
```

If there is just one line (or no line at all), the `do` clause in `for /f` isn't even executed and the script continues with `echo no data.`. If there *is* a second line, the `goto` is executed (thus skipping the rest of the file)

Comment: Just be aware that you could have CSV files with multi-line headers.

Comment: @Compo: good point. Adapt `skip` when the number of header lines is known. If it isn't known, you need some way to distinguish them from data lines.

Comment: @Compo yes I have confirmed regarding the header and it will be always one.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use this approach:

```sh
@Set "}="&(Set /P "="&Set /P "}=")<"response.csv"&If Not Defined } Echo No Data
```

The idea is that the variable named `}` will be defined with the content of line 2 of `response.csv`. If that variable is not defined, it means that there was no content on line 2.

This is a little different to the answer already provided because if the second line was empty, and there was a line 3 with content, it would show as having no data. Therefore this example only reports no data on line 2, not no data beyond line 1.

---

If you want to report no data beyond line 1, here's another alternative:

```sh
findstr /N "^" "response.csv" 2>NUL|findstr /BL "2:">NUL||Echo No Data
```

Although I'd prefer to use full paths and names:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N "^" "Response.csv" 2>NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /L "2:" 1>NUL || Echo No Data
```